# How do I destroy specific button in the loop when clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a 10*10 board of buttons, which when clicked, the clicked button is destroyed and only that one. However, I don't know how to specify which button has been clicked.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Board")
def buttonClick():
    button.destroy()


for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        button = Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10, command=buttonClick)
        button.grid(row=i+1, column=j+1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have your buttonClick callback take the button as a parameter is one way, then when assigning the callbacks with command= use a lambda function or paritial from the functools library so that each button gets its own variant on the callback with itself as an arg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create function which gets `widget`/`button` as argument and uses it with `destroy()`

```
def buttonClick(widget):
    widget.destroy()
```

And first you have to create `Button` without `command=`

```
button = tk.Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10)
```

and later you can use this `button` as argument in `command=`.

```
button["command"] = lambda widget=button:buttonClick(widget)
```

It needs to use `lambda` to assign function with argument.

Because you create many buttons in loop so it also needs to use `widget=button` in `lambda` to create unique variable with value from `button` for every `command`. If you don't use it then all commands will use reference to the same (last) button - and click on every button will destroy only last button.

---

Full working code

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def buttonClick(widget):
    widget.destroy()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Board")

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        button = tk.Button(root, text="x", padx=20, pady=10)
        button["command"] = lambda widget=button:buttonClick(widget)
        button.grid(row=i+1, column=j+1)

root.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily accomplished with a custom class if you're alright with that:

```
from tkinter import Button, Tk


root = Tk()
root.title("Board")


class Self_Destruct_Button(Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.configure(command=self.button_click)

    def button_click(self):
        self.destroy()


for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        button = Self_Destruct_Button(root, text="", padx=20, pady=10)
        button.grid(row=i + 1, column=j + 1)

root.mainloop()
```

So the custom class just assigns the command to a `button_click` method, which destroys the button.

As a side note, I also removed the wildcard import as that's not best practice.

Let me know if this works for you